# How do I change character's image based on user's last input key?

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I can make my character run in left and right direction. I am trying to make my character look in certain direction based on user's input. If user's last command was 'a' or 'K_LEFT', then I would like to make him look in the left direction. Otherwise make him look in the right direction.
I don't know how to achieve this. I looked up at KEYUP in pygame documentation, but  I wasn't able to understand it. Could someone help me here? Here is the code -

```
def animate_char(self):

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        is_resting_forward = True
    if self.rect.bottom != 470:
        self.image = self.player_jump

    elif keys[pygame.K_d] or keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.hero_index += 0.15
        if self.hero_index >= len(self.images_runf_list):
            self.hero_index = 0
        self.image = self.images_runf_list[int(self.hero_index)]
    elif keys[pygame.K_a] or keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.hero_index += 0.15
        if self.hero_index >= len(self.images_runb_list):
            self.hero_index = 0
        self.image = self.images_runb_list[int(self.hero_index)]
        is_resting_forward = False

    else:
        if is_resting_forward:
            self.image = self.image_restf
        else:
            self.image = self.image_restb
```

I am not getting what I wanted from this code. The character sets the value of `self.image_restf` everytime I lift any key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_resting_forward` must be an attribute of the class. Set the attribute depending on the pressed key:

```py
def __init__(self, ......):
    # [...]

    self.is_resting_forward = True
```

```py
def animate_char(self):

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if self.rect.bottom != 470:
        self.image = self.player_jump

    elif keys[pygame.K_d] or keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.hero_index += 0.15
        if self.hero_index >= len(self.images_runf_list):
            self.hero_index = 0
        self.image = self.images_runf_list[int(self.hero_index)]
        self.is_resting_forward = True

    elif keys[pygame.K_a] or keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.hero_index += 0.15
        if self.hero_index >= len(self.images_runb_list):
            self.hero_index = 0
        self.image = self.images_runb_list[int(self.hero_index)]
        slef.is_resting_forward = False

    else:
        if self.is_resting_forward:
            self.image = self.image_restf
        else:
            self.image = self.image_restb
```